# Google Apps Script, anchor creating a redirect when clicked

Tags: anchor, google-apps-script

I'm creating a script that logs a user into a site.  Everything works but for some reason when the user clicks on the link to go to their profile the link opens in a new window and at first redirects before going to the correct page.

For example:

The correct link is: https://sites.google.com/site/examplelehan/Jan_Moolman but the moment the link is clicked the link that is actually executed in the address bar changes to: http://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fexamplelehan%2FJan_Moolman&sa=D&usd=2&usg=AFQjCNFXLLswDh2AWCBpYi54jNXxpZVGPQ

So it seems as if www.google.co.za is being pre-pended to the url.  I've seen other posts as well but none of them seem to be offering working solutions.  A few posts have said that this occurs when the link is created without the http:// prefix but I've tested that and the same problem occurs.

I've also tried using .createHTML in order to create the link but for some reason the link doesn't show, any other HTML I use seems to work so I guess that's why Google created the Anchor function.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: the .createHTML has a limited set of allowed tags, [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850640/in-ui-service-trying-to-view-html-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this issue tracker comment](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1376) Eric [Koleda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702875/eric-koleda) suggested a workaround using [UrlShortener Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlshortener) .  I tested it with [your link](http://goo.gl/HRPfU) [(http://goo.gl/HRPfU)](http://goo.gl/HRPfU) and it seems to be a working solution.

EDIT : to answer your comment, here is a working example :

```
function test(){
var shorturl=short('https://sites.google.com/site/examplelehan/Jan_Moolman');
Logger.log(shorturl);
}
//
function short(longurl){
  var toShorten = UrlShortener.newUrl().setLongUrl(longurl);
  var short = UrlShortener.Url.insert(toShorten).getId();
  return short
  }
```

note that this API has to be activated before it can be used [(see docs)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlshortener)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm having trouble implementing your solution.  Could you perhaps tell me if I'm doing this right?

      var toShorten = UrlShortener.newUrl().setLongUrl(link);
      var shortened = UrlShortener.Url.insert(toShorten);
      Logger.log(shortened.getId());
      profLink.setHref(shortened.getId()).setHTML(
      'Login Successful.Click here to continue.').setVisible(true);

Comment: No but I'm still getting the redirect.

Comment: I tested here and indeed I see a redirect message for a tenth of a second... does that make a real problem for your use case ? or is the redirect different in your case ?

Comment: The redirect happens irrespective of whether or not UrlShortener is used. 

The redirect messages for a tenth of a second is browser specific. Firefox always requires user confirmation before continuing (by default - can be changed). 
However, Chrome shows the redirect message temporarily

The issue reported in the issue tracker is to avoid losing URL parameters.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is a problem in browsers such as Firefox and Internet Explorer.  I'm trying to make it as professional as possible but I understand the problem.  So, I guess there's no way side-stepping the confirmation message in my code or the redirect? 

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: There is no way to avoid the redirect, but it should be automatic, at least when the user is logged in to a Google account.