# how to format a text that I can copy/paste anywhere with data from a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a database program on a spreadsheet with data classically ordered in rows and columns, what I'm working on is a UI that allows the user to search the database and shows results like shown below. The "table" shows the result and the 15 next items in a scrollable table with most important data and a text area in the bottom that should contain the **selected item** in a format that I could copy and paste in any document while keeping the layout (new line, spacing...).Note : the script should also detect wich row in the table has the focus.
This text area should provide 2 (for now) so called 'formats', one for letters as shown in the screen capture and a second with all the fields (commas or tab separated) on a couple of rows (I called it 'raw data') for any other purpose (selection with radioButtons).

I managed to perform search, table populate and UI design but (*here is finally the actual question*) I'm not sure how to get the formatted text in the textarea... should I use HTML ?

Below are the screen capture and the UI code I use for now, I guess the picture makes things a bit more clear, at least I hope ;-)
[image]

```
function buildUi() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("BrowseList Test")
       .setHeight(340).setWidth(800).setStyleAttribute("background-color","beige").setStyleAttribute('padding','20');
    var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(750,150)
    var vpanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
    var cell = new Array();
    var cellWidth = [45,135,150,250,50,100]
    var row = new Array();
    for(vv=0;vv<15;++vv){
      row[vv]=app.createHorizontalPanel();
      vpanel.add(row[vv]);
       for(hh=0;hh<cellWidth.length;++hh){
        cell[hh+(vv)*cellWidth.length]=app.createTextBox().setWidth(cellWidth[hh]+"");
        row[vv].add(cell[hh+(vv)*cellWidth.length])
        }
      }
app.add(scroll.add(vpanel))
// Initial populate
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(vv=0;vv<15;++vv){
       for(hh=0;hh<cellWidth.length;++hh){
         var rowpos=vv+1+offset
         var cellpos = hh+(vv)*cellWidth.length
        cell[cellpos].setValue(data[rowpos][hh])
        }
      }
  var grid = app.createGrid(2,9).setWidth('700')
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('search'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('search').setId('search'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 2, app.createRadioButton('mode','strict'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 3, app.createRadioButton('mode','global').setValue(true));
  grid.setWidget(1, 5, app.createLabel(' ').setWidth('100'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 6, app.createLabel('show mode'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 7, app.createRadioButton('show','letter').setValue(true));
  grid.setWidget(1, 8, app.createRadioButton('show','raw data'));
  app.add(grid);

  var result = app.createTextArea().setPixelSize(700,100)
  app.add(result)

ss.show(app);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the [Rich Text Area](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_richtextarea) ? And use the setHTML method.

Comment: Last time I tried RichTextArea I didn't have much success with it ([*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850640/in-ui-service-trying-to-view-html-content)) but since this time it would be 'hard coded' I'll give it a try and update here.. thanks

Comment: Ok , we can say it works... at least it shows text and I can select and copy/paste but unfortunately HTML rendering is not very rich... I cannot change tipeface nor add so much styles... Anyway, thanks a lot Srik ;-)

Comment: sorry, it seems to be a Browser issue, Typeface don't work on Chrome & Firefox but works on Safari... as style attribute of the richTextArea itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a flextable, to hold your search result. Changing that to the needed format (with commas) and storing via ScriptProperties you can copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks but I want to copy paste directly from the UI - The 'normal user' will only see this UI.

Comment: You're iterating through the row (result) instead off building the result the way you want.If you setId the row items (row number vs position in table), you can access them this way: app.getElementById(`11`).getValue == Mr. + ',' etc.